# Почему space-between не работает?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.row_without_margin {
 padding: 0 15px;
 display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.data_item {
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.date_range {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 13px 6px 13px 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border: 1px solid #e3e4e5;
  /*  flex: 0 0 16.6666666667%;*/

}
#date-range1, #date-range2 {
 height: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border: none;
 width: 80%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    background: url(https://static.sanatorium.com/frontend/common/calendar_new.svg) no-repeat 0 center #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="row_without_margin">
  <div class="data_item">
    <div class="date_range">
      <input id="date-range1" name="daterange" size="40" value="05.02.2018" readonly >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="data_item">
    <div class="date_range">
      <input id="date-range2" name="daterange" size="40" value="Дата выезда" readonly >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search_item">
    <div class="data_item">
      <div class="date_range">
        <div class="guests">
          <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search_item">
    <div class="data_item">
      <div class="date_range">
        <div class="guests">
          <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Привет.Почему в таком варианте стиль space-between не работает?Откройте страницу в полном окне так не будет видно.Тут маленькая пространство и блоки сжались.

Comment: у вас всего один дочерний элемент у data_item, там between нету по сути.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин то есть нужно дочерный элемент создать?

Comment: я не знаю что вы хотите получить, в вопросе этого не сказано, я просто написал почему у вас сейчас `space-between` никак не работает.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я хочу что получить?ну ясно же написано почему не работает  я хочу решить данную проблему и поставить отступы между блоками

Comment: может быть вам надо перенести `space-between` в `row_without_margin`

Comment: у вас тут блоков полно, в вопросе не ясно какие именно части вы хотите проредить через space-between, я же ваши мысли читать не буду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

нужно задавать не item, а контейнеру. Можно обернуть еще в один див

Comment: благодарю вас ...а я то думал уже час почему не работает